# internet explorer 11 web camera compatibility issues

Tags: web, camera, internet-explorer-11

i want to register a volunteer website and to use web camera in the registration page.all the browsers are supporting but except internet explorer 11.so,can anyone tell give some to tip to sort out of it.thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look at https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs
It will gracefully degrade to Flash video for those browsers which do not support HTML5 getUserMedia